# Hook after all shadow variable changes called

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

i am currently working with optaplanner and want to optimize my code so that it wont calculate some value very often to only once per "move".
Therefore i need some kind of hook after all shadow variable change calls are done and now the constraints will get evaluated.

The reason is, that my calculation depends on every other entity and if one changes i will delete the calculated value for all and recalculate it. but in the same shadow variable change i will change another entities and will there also delete for all entities the value and recalculate it till its the last call.
The calculated value is used in the visualization and in constrains. so i cant just calculate it afterwards.

[image]

My only idea is some kind of dirty flag and calculation in the getter. But if there is some kind of hook i could use would be much more elegant and also more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Here at [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/), we are currently dealing with a very similar problem.

As it turns out, if you need to do anything *after* all shadow variables have been processed, that only triggers another round of shadow variable processing. In other words - there is no single point where you could call this final hook; it would only cause an endless cycle.

There seems to be no way around it - if you change variables without notifying the listeners, there will be score corruptions. At the moment, we do not have a solution to the issue, but we are considering some.

Comment: Okay thanks. so im now implementing with my getter idea. the only possible problem i see at the moment is. that opatplanner wont call all constraints while solving. E.g. optaplanner makes a move. starts to evaluate constraints and the first constraint will give a high hard score. is it possible, that optaplanner will skip other constraints cause the hardscore is so bad or can i  rely on it that all constraints (weight > 0) will be evaluated?

Comment: The solver never skips any constraint, it evalutates all of them at once. Of course with the exception of (weight == 0), those are entirely removed from the process.